# How to display value/label pair inside notification template?

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

I would like to display a value/label pair inside of my notification template. For example, assuming I can use {label_name:value}, this method only returns the label name.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try the documentation for freeform entries [here](https://solspace.com/expressionengine/freeform/docs/entries/#freeform_label_field_name)

Basically use  `{freeform:label:FIELD_NAME}`

Comment: Will that return the value of the value/label pair?

Comment: Umm, try it. There's also a value tag. You'll see it on the docs I linked you to.

Comment: That solution doesn't work. Inside my email template there's a tag {cardiology_procedures} but I want return the value like this {cardiology_procedures:value} <- this doesn't work the way I intend.